# Databinding Indexed Property to DataGrid in WPF (C#)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, properties, wpfdatagrid

I have a class in WPF C# that lends itself to have indexed Properties.  I have written the class like so:

```
public class CSIndexedGridRow
{
    private int? [] _columns;

   public  CSIndexedGridRow(int numberOfColumns )
    {
        _columns = new int?[numberOfColumns];
        for (int i =0; i< _columns.Length; i++)
        {
            _columns[i] = null;
        }
    }

    public int RowNumber { get; internal set; }
    public int? this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index >= _columns.Length)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            return _columns[index];
        }
        set{
            if (index >= _columns.Length)
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            if (value != _columns[index])
            {
                _columns[index] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a row number property, and then the indexed property.  The alternative to this would have been to have:

```
public int RowNumber {get; set;}
public int? ColumnA {get; set;}
public int? ColumnB {get; set;}
```

//  ... ad infinitum

This would be a horrible mess.  It (the horrible mess) does have the advantage that the databinding works.  I have a list of these classes:
public List USData

and I databind it to a datagrid like so:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=USData, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   AutoGenerateColumns="True" ></DataGrid>


</Grid>
```

It works fine with the messsy way but not with the indexed properties.  You get all the rows, and the RowNumber is displayed, but the next column is just a big line like this  -------------

What's going on?  How do I databind to a List of objects which have indexed property as one of their properties?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: DataGrid will build rows from a collection but not columns from a collection.  You might be able to override AutoGenerateColumns.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Blam.  Can you elaborate on how I would change the AutoGenerateColumns?  I thought this only had to do with the column headers or titles. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if you can fool it into doing more.  Or don't AutoGenerate at all and build up the columns in code behind.  I do exactly that with a columns collection but with a GridView.